# google search page - barcode input triggers event

Tags: javascript, gwt, web, barcode-scanner

I need a similar thing as google does on their search page. If the user enters something via keyboard or barcode scanner anywhere on the page, this input will be put in the search textbox. It really doesn't matter where the focus is (except other textboxes).

Can someone give me a hint how to handle/capture such events or where those events are triggerd? I need this in an GWT application but native javascript should be ok too.

Answer (score 0):

For input entered via keyboard you should look at the javascript [onkeydown](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeydown.asp) or jQuery [keydown](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) event bound to the body tag.

Barcode scanner are a little more complicated. If the scanner behaves like a keyboard the above should work for the scanner too, but some scanners write the data to the clipboard and paste it under the cursor. If that's the case, see this [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296342/scan-barcode-into-a-specific-textbox/16296532#16296532) from two weeks ago.