# scan barcode in a web application

Tags: javascript, web-applications, barcode, barcode-scanner

I'm building a web application (C#) for a customer.

Now I'm trying to add a page for mobile. I want that the customer will be able to scan a barcode (1D barcode or 2D barcode) and the code will be written in a text field (`<input>`) on the screen for further operations. It must work on android or iphone, and better - on both.

1. I tried to use JS codes which I can take a picture with the camera in the mobile device and the script reads the barcode in the picture - but I didn't find something good enough. 
   [this one](http://manuels.github.io/unix-toolbox.js-exact-image/demo/)  didn't work with large images from the camera, and [this one](http://badassjs.com/post/654334959/barcode-scanning-in-javascript)  couldn't read some of my barcodes and also couldn't read large images.
2. I tried to find a way that the customer will click on a button to open a barcode-scanner-application on the device (I have an android mobile device) - and the barcode will be written on an input on the screen, but I can't find if it's possible and how to do it.
3. I don't want to use phonegap - I need it as a web application, not a native app.

Comment: Alternate solution for small business. Depends on your requirement / feasibility analysis. Instead of developing a barcode reader module, one can purchase a/couple Bluetooth enabled barcode scanner (hardware) ($60) and configure mobile/desktop lookup page to get autofocus on text box. And configure to autofire if detected 'entry by scanner'. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296342/scan-barcode-into-a-specific-textbox . @TamarG I know you are/were seeking help on software solution. Since this solution worked for me, I have mentioned here.

Comment: It also works with USB barcode scanner (I connected it with OTG cable). It still not perfect because it forces us to use external hardware. But maybe better than nothing...