# Ajax call after reading the current text input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20698523/1695685 in order to read value from a handheld barcode scanner. The code works fine as mentioned in the answer (fiddle is attached in the above link)

However, what I am trying to do is to make some ajax calls based on the **current** value of text input after reading a barcode.

The problem I'm facing is that if I scan barcode multiple times I am making ajax calls the same number of times after I press a button (which triggers the ajax call). For e.g. If I read 4 barcodes, I am making the same ajax call( in my case http://localhost:51990/Home/DecodeScanner) 4 times. What I am after is to make only one call after pressing a button, but only read the latest value from the text input box.

Every time I can scan a barcode the text input box is showing the new value (previous values are overridden). However, the ajax call is firing all the previous scans as well on pressing `#scanner-verify-button` button.

This is my modified [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bf89R/475/) with my custom ajax calls

```
/*
    This code will determine when a code has been either entered manually or
    entered using a scanner.
    It assumes that a code has finished being entered when one of the following
    events occurs:
        • The enter key (keycode 13) is input
        • The input has a minumum length of text and loses focus
        • Input stops after being entered very fast (assumed to be a scanner)
*/

var inputStart, inputStop, firstKey, lastKey, timing, userFinishedEntering;
var minChars = 3;

// handle a key value being entered by either keyboard or scanner
$("#scanInput").keypress(function(e) {
  // restart the timer
  if (timing) {
    clearTimeout(timing);
  }

  // handle the key event
  if (e.which == 13) {
    // Enter key was entered

    // don't submit the form
    e.preventDefault();

    // has the user finished entering manually?
    if ($("#scanInput").val().length >= minChars) {
      userFinishedEntering = true; // incase the user pressed the enter key
      inputComplete();
    }
  } else {
    // some other key value was entered

    // could be the last character
    inputStop = performance.now();
    lastKey = e.which;

    // don't assume it's finished just yet
    userFinishedEntering = false;

    // is this the first character?
    if (!inputStart) {
      firstKey = e.which;
      inputStart = inputStop;

      // watch for a loss of focus
      $("body").on("blur", "#scanInput", inputBlur);
    }

    // start the timer again
    timing = setTimeout(inputTimeoutHandler, 500);
  }
});

// Assume that a loss of focus means the value has finished being entered
function inputBlur() {
  clearTimeout(timing);
  if ($("#scanInput").val().length >= minChars) {
    userFinishedEntering = true;
    inputComplete();
  }
};


// reset the page
$("#reset").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  resetValues();
});

function resetValues() {
  // clear the variables
  inputStart = null;
  inputStop = null;
  firstKey = null;
  lastKey = null;
  // clear the results
  inputComplete();
}

// Assume that it is from the scanner if it was entered really fast
function isScannerInput() {
  return (((inputStop - inputStart) / $("#scanInput").val().length) < 15);
}

// Determine if the user is just typing slowly
function isUserFinishedEntering() {
  return !isScannerInput() && userFinishedEntering;
}

function inputTimeoutHandler() {
  // stop listening for a timer event
  clearTimeout(timing);
  // if the value is being entered manually and hasn't finished being entered
  if (!isUserFinishedEntering() || $("#scanInput").val().length < 3) {
    // keep waiting for input
    return;
  } else {
    reportValues();
  }
}

// here we decide what to do now that we know a value has been completely entered
function inputComplete() {
  // stop listening for the input to lose focus
  $("body").off("blur", "#scanInput", inputBlur);
  // report the results
  reportValues();
}

function reportValues() {
  // update the metrics
  $("#startTime").text(inputStart == null ? "" : inputStart);
  $("#firstKey").text(firstKey == null ? "" : firstKey);
  $("#endTime").text(inputStop == null ? "" : inputStop);
  $("#lastKey").text(lastKey == null ? "" : lastKey);
  $("#totalTime").text(inputStart == null ? "" : (inputStop - inputStart) + " milliseconds");
  if (!inputStart) {
    // clear the results
    $("#resultsList").html("");
    $("#scanInput").focus().select();
  } else {
    // prepend another result item
    var inputMethod = isScannerInput() ? "Scanner" : "Keyboard";
    $("#resultsList").prepend("<div class='resultItem " + inputMethod + "'>" +
      "<span>Value: " + $("#scanInput").val() + "<br/>" +
      "<span>ms/char: " + ((inputStop - inputStart) / $("#scanInput").val().length) + "</span></br>" +
      "<span>InputMethod: <strong>" + inputMethod + "</strong></span></br>" +
      "</span></div></br>");
    $("#scanInput").focus().select();
    inputStart = null;

    // Some transformations

    const barcodeString = $("#scanInput").val();

    const productCode = barcodeString.substring(5, 19);
    const serialNumber = barcodeString.substring(36, 46);
    const batch = barcodeString.substring(29, 34);
    const expirationDate = barcodeString.substring(21, 27);

    // AJAX calls
    $('#scanner-verify-button').click(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "DecodeScanner",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          productCode: productCode,
          serialNumber: serialNumber,
          batch: batch,
          expirationDate: expirationDate,
          commandStatusCode: 0
        },
        async: true,
        success: function(data) {
          $('#pTextAreaResult').text(data);
        }
      });
    });
  }
}

$("#scanInput").focus();
```

HTML

```
<form>
    <input id="scanInput" />
    <button id="reset">Reset</button>
</form>
<br/>
<div>
    <h2>Event Information</h2> Start: <span id="startTime"></span>
    <br/>First Key: <span id="firstKey"></span>
    <br/>Last Ley: <span id="lastKey"></span>
    <br/>End: <span id="endTime"></span>
    <br/>Elapsed: <span id="totalTime"></span>

</div>
<div>
    <h2>Results</h2>

    <div id="resultsList"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <button id="scanner-verify-button" type="submit">Verify</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the ajax call inside block `$('#scanner-verify-button').click(function() {}` was attaching new listener to the button on everytime the `reportValues()` call waas made.

I was able to solve this by moving the ajax calls in its own block

```
// Check for any input changes

var productCode, serialNumber, batch, expirationDate;

$("#scanInput").on("change paste keyup", function () {
    barcodeString = $("#scanInput").val();
    productCode = barcodeString.substring(5, 19);
    serialNumber = barcodeString.substring(36, 46);
    batch = barcodeString.substring(29, 34);
    expirationDate = barcodeString.substring(21, 27);
}); 

// Ajax calls
$("#scanner-verify-button").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "DecodeScanner",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            productCode: productCode,
            serialNumber: serialNumber,
            batch: batch,
            expirationDate: expirationDate,
            commandStatusCode: 0
        },
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#pTextAreaResult').text(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bf89R/477/)

Answer (score 0):

As per the code, the click handler for the scanner button seems to be registered multiple times.

The click handler should be registered only once.

The `reportValues()` is called multiple times which registers the click handler multiple times. This means when you press the button, all the click handlers get called and ajax request gets triggered.

You need to put the click handler outside of any function which can get called multiple times.

Also as per the code, all the variables which need to be accessed by the click handler should be declared outside reportValues.

Comment: How do I avoid that?

Comment: I can put the click handler outside the `reportValues()` but then how do I fetch the latest updated text input value?

Comment: You can set the latest updated text values in variables defined outside reportValues. Then the click handler can access those variables.

Comment: Can you show me a sample code on how do I fetch the text values in variables outside the `reportValues` block and call the click handler afterwards?